# Time taken for a floor to reach the ground

Tags: mathematical-physics

So the question is as follows:

A building has $s$ floors each of height $h$. An explosion destroys the strength of the $n^{th}$ floor. You may assume that the building remains intact above the floor that explodes and that the momentum is conserved in the collisions of the successive stories during the fall of the building. Estimate the time before the $(n+1)^{th}$ floor hits the ground falling vertically.

So I used the formula
$$s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2$$

$$nh = 0(t) + \frac{1}{2}9.8t^2$$

$$t = \sqrt{\frac{nh}{4.9}}$$

But I dont know how the momentum comes into play

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please include LaTex in your questions (this can help: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: You might be able to get an answer here but this question is more suited to Physics Stack Exchange IMO.